# log4net debug logs are not shown even if debug level is set to true

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore in my ASP.NET Core 5.0 web application.

The logging is enabled in Startup.cs as this:

```
services.AddLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.AddLog4Net("log4net.config", true);
});
```

Unfortunately DEBUG Logs are not shown in the logfile / console even if I set the level to DEBUG?!

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
            <conversionPattern value="%date %5level %logger.%method [%line] - MESSAGE: %message%newline %exception" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="log/WebApp.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %5level %logger.%method [%line] - MESSAGE: %message%newline %exception" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %5level %logger.%method [%line] - MESSAGE: %message%newline %exception" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ManagedColoredConsoleAppender">
        <mapping>
            <level value="ERROR" />
            <foreColor value="Red" />
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
            <level value="WARN" />
            <foreColor value="Yellow" />
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <foreColor value="White" />
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <foreColor value="Green" />
        </mapping>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %5level %logger.%method [%line] - MESSAGE: %message%newline %exception" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Check the appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json file, whether you have set the log level from here? Besides, whether you are using Log Filter or not? If use, try to remove the filter or change the filter. Reference: [Middleware Debug logs are not forwarded to log4net provider](https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore/issues/70)

Comment: thank you , that solved my issue. I was overriding with appsettings.Development.json my appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

Configure logging for you HostBuilder. Tipicaly code in program.cs

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            var HostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
            
            HostBuilder
             

              .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
              {
                  logging.AddLog4Net(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "cfg", "log4net.config"));
                  logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
              })
              .UseStartup<Startup>();
            return HostBuilder;
        }
    }
```